# SQL Update a DateRange table from a SUM query of another table

Tags: sql

Table DateRangeTab (Fromdate, Todate, TotalValue) has data such as:

```
2010-01-01, 2011-01-01, 0
2010-01-01, 2012-01-01, 0
```

etc (i.e lots of date ranges all with 0 in the TotalValue column)

I also have table ValueTab (DateofValue, Value) which has data such as:

```
2010-01-02, £25
2011-01-01, £45
2011-05-04, £65
```

etc (i.e. lots of different rows with dates and a value for each date)

I need to update DateRangeTab TotalValue column with SUM of Value from ValueTab table where the DateofValue falls in the range FromDate - Todate.

I tried something like the following :

```
Update DateRangeTab 
set TotalValue = a.Value
from (select sum(value) as Value 
     from ValueTab VT 
     join DateRangeTab DT 
     on VT.DateofValue between DT.startdate and DT.ToDate) a
```

But it puts same total in each row of the DateRangeTab.
Hope someone can help or direct me to another post with a related answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Update daterangetab 
set totalvalue=(select sum(value) 
                from valuetab 
                 where dateofvalue >= fromdate and dateofvalue <= todate 
group by dateofvalue);
```

This works in postgresql

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
update DateRangeTab a 
set TotalValue = (select sum(value)
                from ValueTab 
                where DateofValue between a.Fromdate and a.Todate
                group by DateofValue)
```

I cannot test this so it is very approximate... Try and adapt it to your needs.